# Jquery mouseover sprite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi how to write an jquery code that can use to rating a price rating? Below are screenshot of the image
[image]

The html code for this code are as follow:

```
<fieldset id="price_choices">
        <legend class="offscreen">Price Range:</legend>
            <p class="offscreen">Price per person:</p>
        <ul class="clearfix price-1">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="price-1" name="RestaurantsPriceRange2" value="1">               <label for="price-1" class="offscreen">

                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="price-2" name="RestaurantsPriceRange2" value="2">               <label for="price-2" class="offscreen">

                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="price-3" name="RestaurantsPriceRange2" value="3">               <label for="price-3" class="offscreen">

                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="price-4" name="RestaurantsPriceRange2" value="4">               <label for="price-4" class="offscreen">

                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
```

for the css that render the sprite image of rating are as follow:

```
#price_choices ul {
padding: 0 7px;
height: 28px;
background: url(../images/dollars.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#price_choices li {
width: 20px;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
#price_choices li {
padding: 0;
float: left;
}
#price_choices input {
margin: 0!important;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
cursor: pointer;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-moz-opacity: 0;
opacity: 0;

}
#price_choices ul.price-1 {
background-position: 0 -28px;
}
#price_choices ul.price-2 {
background-position: 0 -56px;
}
#price_choices ul.price-3 {
background-position: 0 -84px;
}
#price_choices ul.price-4 {
background-position: 0 -112px;
}
```

The image sprite dollars.gif as as follow:
[image]

Also when user mouseover on each li element the dollar sign keep adding, and when user click on particular li, Jquery should alert value for that particular li.Thanks

Comment: So did you try anything, or you just want us to get it ready for you?

Comment: @MikeSpy i have a similar jquery function but it doesnt works for this, i use it for star rating

Comment: There is a lot of star rating jQuery plugins... and you can't even find one that suit you?

Comment: @ByScripts yes there is alot, none of them using sprite as image.

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo I don't understand why you want to use such a sprite. It's not scalable (if tomorrow you decide to have 5 "dollars", you'll need to redo the image). A good sprite would be one with only 1 "on" and 1 "off", repeated as needed. (Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

This one is similar to star rating

I am using a javascript for similar thing.

I thnk this will help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $('#default').raty();


                $('#half').raty({
                    half    : true,
                    score   : 3.3
                });

                $('#round').raty({
                    score   : 1.26,
                    round   : { down: .25, full: .6, up: .76 }
                });


                $('#precision').raty({
                    half        : true,
                    path        : 'doc/img/', /* the path of your $ images*/
                    precision   : true,
                    size        : 24,
                    starOff     : 'star-off-big.png',//grey image of $
                    starOn      : 'star-on-big.png',//green img of $
                    target      : '#precision-target',
                    targetKeep  : true,
                    targetType  : 'number'
                });



            });
        </script>
```

then add the below in your HTML part:

```
<div id="precision"></div>
<input type="text" id="precision-target" name="txt"/></div><br/>
```

also download **jquery.raty.min.js** and include it in your page

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood, something like that should be working

```
$('ul').mouseover(function(){
 var ind = $(this).find('input').val();
 var shift = (ind-2)*28;
 $(this).css('background-position', '0 ' +shift+ 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of resources on the web to do that... Have search a minimum?

[Very detailed todo](http://eligeske.com/jquery/jquery-star-comment-rating/)

[Or all made plugins](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/)

[Even some compilations](http://www.enfew.com/5-best-jquery-star-rating-plugins-tutorials/)

[Or maybe this one?](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jrating)

[Or a bigger compilation ;)](https://www.google.fr/?q=jquery+star+rating)